# Updating configuration for Play without downtime

Tags: configuration, playframework, production-environment

I want to change settings -- adjust timeouts, enable flags, etc. -- without the downtime of restarting the Play server. Is there a good way to do this?

---

My current idea:

Play supports [external configuration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ProductionConfiguration) files.

In my case, I am using Chef to manage the external configuration file.

If the external configuration file changes, will subsequent calls to configuration reflect those changes, or will I have to restart the Play server?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I'm looking into allowing settings to be updated by editing a database field and don't want to have to restart my Play server.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to restart.  Java classpaths are immutable (excluding things like JRebel) and Play's config file is loaded from the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a load balancer, haproxy for example, with 2 instances of application. When you need to reconfigure, just drop onde of the instances of the load balancer. And after you enable again.

Alberto

Comment: Yes, this would work for any server. Very general, and also non-trivial to implement.